# Executing multiple tests paths using craftcms and codeception

Tags: php, yii2, codeception, craftcms

For a Craft CMS/Yii2 project using Codeception I'd like to execute testing on multiple plugins, meaning from multiple sources within the *vendor* directory.

https://codeception.com/docs/reference/Configuration

Sadly the above documentation only seems to mention a single option for the 'tests' file path. Would it be possible and advisable to somehow implement this, for example by using symbolic links?

Current situation:

```
paths:
    tests: tests,
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
```

Example of desired situation:

```
paths:
    tests: vendor/foo/bar/tests, vendor/foofoo/barbar/tests
    [...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If plugins have codeception.yaml files, you can use [include setting](https://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#One-Runner-for-Multiple-Applications)

```
include:
  - vendor/foo/bar
  - vendor/foofoo/barbar
```

Generally it is a bad idea to run test suites of libraries as part of testing your application. You should trust libraries that they are well tested and don't make releases with broken tests.